# adjust plotly xaxis ticks number with parameter

Tags: plotly-python

I would like to adjust the plotly xaxis ticks number to 12. I guess there should have a parameter to do that if anyone knows it!

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import datetime

import plotly.graph_objects as go

def save_fig(fig,pngname):
    fig.write_image(pngname,format="png", width=800, height=400, scale=1)
    print("[[%s]]"%pngname)    
    return

def plot_stems(df):
    fig = go.Figure()
    traces = []
    xname = df.columns[0]
    color = 'blue'
    lw=1
    for i,yname in enumerate(df.columns):
        if i == 0: continue
        trace1 = go.Scatter(
            x=df[xname], y=df[yname],
            mode = 'markers',#'lines', 'markers', 'text'
            marker=dict(color=color,size=1.5*lw),
            error_y=dict(
                type='data',
                array=[0]*len(df[yname]),           
                arrayminus=df[yname],
                color=color,
                thickness=1,
                width=0,
            ),        
        )        
        traces.append(trace1)
        
    fig.add_traces(traces)
    fig.update_layout(
        margin=dict(l=10,t=40,r=10,b=40),
        plot_bgcolor='#ffffff',#'rgb(12,163,135)',
        paper_bgcolor='#ffffff',        
        title="title",
        xaxis_title="x",
        yaxis_title="y",
        title_x=0.5,
        barmode='group',
        bargap=0.05,
        bargroupgap=0.0,
        legend=dict(x=.02,y=1),
        xaxis=dict(
            tickangle=-25,            
            tickformat = '%m-%d %H:%M:%S',#datetime format
            showline=True,
            linecolor='black',
            color='black',
            linewidth=.5,
            ticks='outside',
        ),
        yaxis=dict(
            showline=True,
            linecolor='black',
            color='black',
            linewidth=.5,            
            showgrid=True,
            gridcolor='grey',#'#ececec',
            gridwidth=.5,
            griddash='solid',#'dot',
            zeroline=True,
            zerolinecolor='grey',
            zerolinewidth=.5,
            showticklabels=True,
        ),        
    )
    fig.show()
    return

def main():
    data = [
        ["2023-04-01 12:00:00.123",1],
        ["2023-04-01 12:00:10.123",2],
        ["2023-04-01 12:00:20.123",1],
        ["2023-04-01 12:00:30.123",5],
        ["2023-04-01 12:00:40.123",10],
        ["2023-04-01 12:00:50.123",8],
        ["2023-04-01 12:01:00.123",6],
        ["2023-04-01 12:01:10.123",9],
        ["2023-04-01 12:01:20.123",10],
        ["2023-04-01 12:01:30.123",2],
        ["2023-04-01 12:01:40.123",5],
        ["2023-04-01 12:01:50.123",9],
        ["2023-04-01 12:02:30.123",2],
        ["2023-04-01 12:02:40.123",5],
        ["2023-04-01 12:02:50.123",9],
    ]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['ts','value'])
    df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'],format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

    plot_stems(df)
    return

main()
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Quick and dirty solution**: `xaxis_nticks = 20`
*here plotly will draw 20 or less ticks at suitable positions*
[image: fig.update_layout(xaxis_nticks = 20)]
**Working example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def plot_stems(df):
    fig = go.Figure()
    traces = []
    xname = df.columns[0]
    color = 'blue'
    lw=4
    for i,yname in enumerate(df.columns):
        if i == 0: continue
        trace1 = go.Scatter(
            x=df[xname], y=df[yname],
            mode = 'markers',#'lines', 'markers', 'text'
            marker=dict(color=color,size=1.5*lw),
            error_y=dict(
                type='data',
                array=[0]*len(df[yname]),           
                arrayminus=df[yname],
                width=0),)        
        traces.append(trace1)
        
    fig.add_traces(traces)
    fig.update_layout(
        xaxis=dict(
            showgrid = False,
            tickangle=-25,            
            tickformat = '%m-%d %H:%M:%S',#datetime format
            nticks = 20,
        ),
        yaxis=dict(
            zeroline=True,
        ),        
    )
    fig.show()
    return


data = [
    ["2023-04-01 12:00:00.123",1],
    ["2023-04-01 12:00:10.123",2],
    ["2023-04-01 12:00:20.123",1],
    ["2023-04-01 12:00:30.123",5],
    ["2023-04-01 12:00:40.123",10],
    ["2023-04-01 12:00:50.123",8],
    ["2023-04-01 12:01:00.123",6],
    ["2023-04-01 12:01:10.123",9],
    ["2023-04-01 12:01:20.123",10],
    ["2023-04-01 12:01:30.123",2],
    ["2023-04-01 12:01:40.123",5],
    ["2023-04-01 12:01:50.123",9],
    ["2023-04-01 12:02:30.123",2],
    ["2023-04-01 12:02:40.123",5],
    ["2023-04-01 12:02:50.123",9],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['ts','value'])
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'],format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

plot_stems(df)
```

**Slower in terms of implementation, but more controlled version**: see the official documentation and try to play with tickvals variable

> `fig.update_xaxes(ticktext=<VALUE>)` Type: *list, numpy
> array, or Pandas series of numbers, strings, or datetimes*. Sets the
> text displayed at the ticks position via `tickvals`. Only has an
> effect if `tickmode` is set to "array". Used with `tickvals`.
>
> `fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=<VALUE>)` Type: *list, numpy
> array, or Pandas series of numbers, strings, or datetimes*. Sets the
> values at which ticks on this axis appear. Only has an effect if
> `tickmode` is set to "array". Used with `ticktext`.
>
> `fig.update_xaxes(tickmode=<VALUE>)` Type: *enumerated , one of (
> "auto" | "linear" | "array" | "sync" )*
> Sets the tick mode for this
> axis. If "auto", the number of ticks is set via `nticks`. If "linear",
> the placement of the ticks is determined by a starting position
> `tick0` and a tick step `dtick` ("linear" is the default value if
> `tick0` and `dtick` are provided). If "array", the placement of the
> ticks is set via `tickvals` and the tick text is `ticktext`. ("array"
> is the default value if `tickvals` is provided). If "sync", the number
> of ticks will sync with the overlayed axis set by `overlaying`
> property.